# Statistical independence of two random variables that are functions of the same random variables

Tags: probability

Given the R.V. $x$, $y$ and $z$, we have:

$u=f(x,y)$

$v=g(x,y,z)$

Can $u$ and $v$ be independent?

The covariance $Cov(u,v)=0$, and I've proved that $E[UV]-E[U]E[V]=0$. But intuitively I have strong difficulties to accept that they can be independent.

Any clarity you could shed will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If $f$ is a function of $x$ and $g $ is a function of $z$ and $x,z$ are independent then $u,v$ will be independent. On the other hand, a zero covariance does not imply independence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they can be independent.  Even if $Y=f(X)$ and $Z=g(X)$, it can happen that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent, if $X$ is something like uniform on $[0,1]$. Consider: write $X$ in binary (so $X=\sum B_n 2^{-n}$, where the $B_n$ are iid Bernoulli random variables) and find an $f$ that only looks at the even bits $B_{2n}$ and a $g$ that  only looks at the odd bits $B_{2n+1}$.

Or, let $\theta$ be uniform on $[0,2\pi)$ and let $R^2$ be an independent chi-squared rv on 2 degrees of freedom.  Then it is well known that $X=R \cos\theta$ and $Y=R\sin\theta$ are iid standard normal rvs.

At any rate, the situation you describe can & does occur.

Comment: I see... The examples are very clear! 
It challenges however what (I think) I know what independence is... In my case:

$u=\frac{x}{x+y}$

$v=\frac{z}{x+y+z}$

How do you know if they are independent?

Comment: Your second example hits the nail on the head.

Comment: Ram, I don't know of a simple recipe.  Perform the change of variables, work out the joint density of $(u,v)$, and see if it factors into a function of $u$ alone times a function of $v$ alone.  This can be laborious.